# All query read only except one

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a university project (database creation on MySQL Workbench) and I have a question

All the queries I've created are working. All of their results are "read only" and so the results are not editable (that's fine). All except one. The one with the construct "NOT IN" outputs a results table that is editable and I don't know if it is my fault or Workbench one.
The query looks working fine (the results are correct) but the fact that it's the only one editable makes me unconfortable (I couldn't justify it to my professor in case he asked).
Here's the query:

```
SELECT c.`Codice Concessionario` 
  FROM concessionario AS c 
 WHERE c.`Codice Concessionario` NOT IN  
            (SELECT c1.`Codice Concessionario` 
               FROM concessionario AS c1 
               JOIN rifornisce AS r 
                 ON r.CodiConcess = c1.`Codice Concessionario`
               JOIN fabbrica AS f 
                 ON f.ID = r.IDFabbrica
              WHERE r.IDFabbrica = 'F2')
```

Thnaks for your answers!

Comment: Do you want the queries to be read-only? Do your other queries include a `JOIN` in the main query?

Comment: does `... FROM (table inner join table2)` even work ?

Comment: Yes, even the other queries contain a JOIN and I didn't touch any settings for "read only" or else. I noticed only that all the other queries are read only and I can0t explain why this one is editable

Comment: Answer to Cid: yes the query works as inteded (the output shown is right) but I don't know why it's editable as long as all the other queries are read only and I didn't change any setting

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry for that @Strawberry and thanks for the correction. Anyway I still don't undestand why the result is editable